# Multiple aliases of a single table column with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to have multiple Aliases from a single table column. If I do the following in MySQL I get the result I want:

```
SELECT name, name AS label, name AS value FROM `tags` WHERE 1
```

But, if I try to do:

```
$query->select('name, name AS label, name AS value');
```

..it tells me `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name,' in 'field list' (SQL: select`name,`as`AS`from`tags`where`tags`.`deleted_at`is null group by`name`order by`name`asc)`

If I try to do

```
$query->select('name AS name, name AS label, name AS value');
```

..it doesn't throw an error, but instead only gives me one alias (name). How can I achieve this using Eloquent ORM? Thanks

Comment: Try to use `selectRaw` instead of `select`

Answer (score 2):

When you try select laravel do this:

```
public function select($columns = array('*'))
{
    $this->columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();

    return $this;
}
```

And when you pass the string, laravel thinks you passed few args, so you can do:

```
$query->select(['name AS name', 'name AS label', 'name AS value']);
```

Or

```
$query->selectRaw('name AS name, name AS label, name AS value'):
```

Or

```
$query->select(DB::raw('name AS name, name AS label, name AS value'));
```

Or like said @Jarek Tkaczyk

```
$query->select('name as name', 'name as label', 'name as value');
```

Comment: most straightforward would be either array, like your 1st piece, or strings `select('col', 'col as alias_1', 'col as alias_2')`, so add it. Also, worth noting: you **must use `as` to alias a column**, otherwise it won't work: `select('col alias') -> wrong`, despite in xSQLs would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$query->select(DB::raw('name AS name, name AS label, name AS value'));`

[Link of Laravel Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions)